# Bounded Darboux Function without Absolute Maximum on Closed Interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Is there an example of a Darboux function which is bounded on the closed interval $[0,1]$ but achieves no absolute maximum on $[0,1]$? While I am trying to find any such function, I would prefer one that is as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(0)=0$, $f(x)=e^{-x}\cos\frac1x$ for $0\lt x\le1$.